# flutter - an issue with Future.builder in Cloud Firestore 0.14

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I updated the cloud firestore yesterday. And, I surprised everything about firestore became wrong. I tried to update my code but I still getting an error with the Future builder. Here is the code and the error. The code was ok before the update.

```
  Future getposts() async{
await Firebase.initializeApp();
var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("Restaurants").get();
  return qn.docs;}


 FutureBuilder(
                    future: getposts(),
                    builder: (_,snapshot){
                      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );}
                      else{
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data().length,
                          itemBuilder: (_,index){
                            return Center(
                              child: Text(snapshot.data()[index].data()["name"]),
                            );
                          },);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
```

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> **The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#2c7a5):
> Class 'List' has no instance method 'call'.
> Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'
> Tried calling: call()**

The relevant error-causing widget was:
FutureBuilder file:///C:/Users/youse/AndroidStudioProjects/new_app/lib/screens/main_page.dart:226:23
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _MainPageState.build. (package:new_app/screens/main_page.dart:235:55)
#2      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:740:55)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4663:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4546:15)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. I solved the issue by removing the parenthesis in the first data. And here is the correct code.

```
 Future getposts() async{
await Firebase.initializeApp();
var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("Restaurants").get();
  return qn.docs;}

FutureBuilder(
                    future: getposts(),
                    builder: (_,snapshot){
                      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );}
                      else{
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (_,index){
                            return Center(
                              child: Text(snapshot.data[index].data()["name"]),
                            );
                          },);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
```